# The most efficient method updating images

Tags: iphone, xcode, image

I am just after some advice re the most efficient method of adding new images to my App.

I need to store 80+ new 300 x 100 pixel images to my app every couple of weeks.

I am worried it will take to long to download these images in the background.

What is the most efficient method of updating and storing this image data?

Is the most efficient method simply releasing an update of the app to itunes?

Answer (score 1):

you may use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)   , and you don't have to worry about cache and etc

Web Image
This library provides a category for UIImageVIew with support for remote images coming from the web.

It provides:

An UIImageView category adding web image and cache management to the Cocoa Touch framework
An asynchronous image downloader
An asynchronous memory + disk image caching with automatic cache expiration handling
A guarantee that the same URL won't be downloaded several times
A guarantee that bogus URLs won't be retried again and again
Performances!